# how to create sub-interface

Tags: networking, server, netplan

`kernel : ubuntu server LTS 22.04.1`

I am trying to create sub-interface via netplan in ubuntu unfortunately this doesn't work
can any body help me ?
i rather not use vlans but if you can do it with vlan it's a great help
i feel like it's not possible with netplan can i use any other tool ?

```
network:   
version: 2   
renderer: networkd   
ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - <ip>/24
      gateway4: <gateway>
    eth0:1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

Comment: If your Ubuntu version is just 22 then that is Ubuntu Core 22 as this is the only version with a single digit version. If this is not correct please EDIT the question and correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a secondary IP on the same link an a vlan configuration. I guess you want to have a secondary IP on the same link, without a vlan configuration.
A netplan file with multiple Ips on the same link looks like

```
network:   
  version: 2   
  renderer: networkd   
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 1.2.3.4/24
        - 1.2.3.5/24   # same subnet 
        - 6.7.8.9/24   # different subnet
```

Please note: you may see secondary Ips with the command `ip a` but not with the legacy command `ifconfig`.

If you need 2 bridge interfaces and you have only one physical interface you must work with vlans.

```
The netplan config looks like 
network:   
  version: 2   
  renderer: networkd   
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no

  vlans:
    vlan10:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 10
      link: ens192
    vlan20:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 20
      link: ens192

  bridges:
    br-internal:
      interfaces: [ vlan10 ]
      addresses: [ 10.3.99.25/24 ]


br-external:
  interfaces: [ vlan20 ]
```

see netplan documentation for all options.
https://netplan.io/examples/#configuring-network-bridges

Comment: no i don't want to have multiple ips on one interface i want to split my network card for 
cloud computing purposes

Comment: the traditional way of `eth0` `eth0:1` `eth0:2` is nothing else than multiple IPs on one interface. Maybe you should describe more clearly what you want.

Comment: in openstack networking for flat networks you need to assign 2 interfaces (br-internal , br-external) to neutron module this interfaces shouldn't have any IPs they will get managed by neutron itself my problem is couple of my production servers only have 1 network interfaces so i need to find a way to split my network card so i can create separate bridges on each of the interfaces and add them to openvswitch

Comment: I extended my answer ... you will need vlans.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Netplan does not have aliases ("sub-interface" per your wording) but does allow labeling of interfaces.

**The long answer**

I, too, was looking for something like this.
There are a few things to parse out here.

First, a "sub-interface" is, strictly speaking, an interface alias and they are now "obsolete".
Per:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/alias.html

> IP-aliases are an obsolete way to manage multiple IP-addresses/masks per interface. Newer tools such as iproute2 support multiple address/prefixes per interface, but aliases are still supported for backwards compatibility.

At this fundamental level, aliases are supported by the Linux kernel. However, I believe the ability to create aliases for interfaces comes from older network configuration tools like `ifconfig` and `route`

Second, the `iproute2` package and its utilities are the modern approach to network configuration.  It allows assigning multiple addresses to an interface without the need for aliases.

Third, netplan, it is yet another new approach to configuring networks and interfaces, via yaml files.

Specific to your question, you will wind up defining different routes per IP address on your interface. Netplan **DOES** provide labeling of interfaces but I don't believe this is necessary for you to achieve your goals. (From the documentation)

```
ethernets:
enp3s0:
  addresses:
    - 10.100.1.37/24
    - 10.100.1.38/24:
        label: "enp3s0:0"
    - 10.100.1.39/24:
        label: "enp3s0:some-label"
```

https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/#how-to-use-multiple-addresses-on-a-single-interface

NB! In netplan configs, `gateway4` is deprecated, so use `routes` as displayed in the documentation. (It doesn't error, yet, but it does give warnings.)

https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/#how-to-use-multiple-addresses-with-multiple-gateways

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
        - 10.0.0.10/24
        - 11.0.0.11/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.0.1
          metric: 200
        - to: default
          via: 11.0.0.1
          metric: 300
```

---

Further reading, links specific to adding multiple addresses on a loopback, just in case someone comes looking.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/+bug/1968287

https://github.com/canonical/netplan.io/pull/225

```
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
  lo:
    match:
        name: lo
    addresses: [ "127.0.0.1/8", "::1/128", "7.7.7.7/32" ]
```

Comment: no i don't want to have multiple ips on one interface i want to split my network card for cloud computing purposes. the second interface is raw with no ip or gateway it get's managed by openstack-neutron. i edited yaml file.